# How do I get webpack to rebuild server.js on every change and nodemon to restart the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, nodemon

My `package.json` script to run in development mode is this:

```
"scripts": {
 "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon src/server.js",
}
```

`server.js` itself makes use of a function that runs `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware` and seems to work fine-ish.

The problem is that `server.js` is not being built by Webpack because I am asking `nodemon` to restart `server.js` on changes.

How could I get `server.js` to be built by Webpack, and then use `nodemon` to restart the built version of `server.js` on every change? At least thats how I think it should work logically in my head.

I need `server.js` to be built by Webpack (even in dev) because it uses ES6 syntax which needs to be transpiled by `babel` for any of it to work. If I run a production build, then server.js gets built with all my other files so works fine when served from `dist/server.js` but not from `src/server.js` which is required for development work.

Comment: You need to run those two things in parallel, watching the source to rebuild and the output to restart. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/a9dbc822ababf8d38f40c3f5ffee4d640e16e910/package.json#L14-L17. Again this seems like an odd use of Webpack, which is designed for bundling *client-side* code, just use Babel directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, in your dev setup are you rebuilding the entire client and server into `dist`? I am trying to use HMR so that I don't have to rebuild the entire thing on every change.

Comment: No; WDS is in-memory, only the backend code is in `dist/` when the dev mode is running.

Comment: I would ideally like to serve everything from `src/` and have all the webpack built files in memory. Using `webpack-dev-middleware` I have managed to do this, but because I need to run `src/sever.js` for development, it is not transpiled. I want the transpiled version in memory and not to mutate `src/server.js` itself - is this possible?

Comment: Why is that ideal? Then have you looked into e.g. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html? Why is anything mutating `src/server.js` in either case, you should output to a *different* directory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe babel-node solved my whole problem! thank you so much! it transpiles server.js in memory. I just run it like `nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js` and its all transpiled. If you want to post it as an answer I can vote it as answer!